# Is it possible to develop a running laravel website on a shared host with no access to ssh

Tags: laravel, git, shared-hosting

I have problem with development of my laravel website on a shared host.
I cant access to ssh and git commands and development spend a lot of time because of write and test every section in local environment and put it to up and running website.
Is there any way to easier development ?
again, there is no way to use ssh.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: How do you have access ? FTP ?

Comment: Testing in local before deployment seems like a reasonable workflow. I'm not sure I completely understood your situation but developing directly on the host using SSH is very risky.

Comment: you can write a script (possibly php or something) that you can upload and execute commands. it wont be ssh and it is not ideal or secure but you can do something like `exec($command)` and have command be a post request parameter or something. alternatively i highly suggest getting a Virtual Host they are soo cheap these days i doubt that they are more expensive than a shared host. vultr has them for $2.5/month

Comment: try to deploy your project into VPS or VDS

Comment: @matthiasbe I have access to the ftp